# Shopware 6: Media upload/field as custom field in app-manifest

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

Can i use a media field as custom field in a app manifest?

The following example is not working:

```
<custom-field-set>
            ...
            <related-entities>
                <category/>
            </related-entities>
            <fields>
           
                <many-to-one name="vendorname-image" reference="media" store-api-aware="true" on-delete="set-null" >
                    <position>2</position>
                    <label>Image for megamenu</label>
                    <label lang="de-DE">Bild für Megamenü</label>
                </many-to-one>
            </fields>
        </custom-field-set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up elements for [fields of custom entities](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/custom-data/custom-entities) and elements for actual [custom fields](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/custom-data/custom-fields). The correct element would be `media-selection` for a custom field that contains the id of a `media` entity.

```xml
<manifest ...>
    <custom-fields>
        <custom-field-set>
            <name>swag_example_set</name>
            <label>Example Set</label>
            <related-entities>
                <category/>
            </related-entities>
            <fields>
                <media-selection name="vendorname_image">
                    <position>2</position>
                    <label>Image for megamenu</label>
                    <label lang="de-DE">Bild für Megamenü</label>
                </media-selection>
            </fields>
        </custom-field-set>
    </custom-fields>
</manifest>
```